BSOD on connecting laptop to projector. PC won't boot now and no HDD/SDD shown in BIOS
Problem: So my Toshiba laptop ran into a BSOD (I didn't note the error msg) the moment I connected it to a working projector screen using an HDMI I think. I disconnected the projector but now on boot it says:

Checking media presence. No media present

And on pressing a key:

Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

Some context: This was the first time I connected it to a projector. And the BSOD and boot issue never happened before.
(It did boot successfully randomly once but then ran into a BSOD again.)
Note that in the BIOS:

No HDD or SDD are present
No boot manager is showing
Highest priority is HDD/SDD
UEFI is chosen
I don't see any PXE related terms

Finally, the laptop has an SSD and HDD. Both have always worked. Windows 10 is installed in the SSD but might also be in HDD.
Any help is appreciated.

Does your laptop boot when projector is not connected?

@Toto No, the issue happens both with and without a projector.

The message "Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key," indicates the internal SSD and HDD have been damaged or disconnected, or the hardware controller(s) for them was damaged.
This is further confirmed by the devices not showing up in BIOS.
As a test, try booting from USB, such as with live Linux (e.g., Ubuntu), Hiren's BootCD PE, or an alternative. If it can boot from USB, then you've confirmed the PC can still boot, but the issue is with SSD, HDD or controllers.
Try removing and reseating the SSD and HDD, which might be loose in sockets. If that does not fix the issue, the PC likely needs professional repair.
